# Android Kotlin ViewPager2 and TabLayout in a fragment not showing up on the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, android-viewpager2

The code works fine and compiles without error, the application opens, and the bottom nav works, but the fragment where I put my view pager and tab layout is empty. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuSjs.jpg).

Since there is no error at compilation or the logcat, I don't know what to try.

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.browse.BrowseFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/browse_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/browse_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/browse_tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my adapter

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter


private const val NUM_TABS = 2

public class BrowsePagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return NUM_TABS
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return RadarFragment()
            1 -> return MatchFragment()
        }
        return RadarFragment()
    }
}
```

and my fragment that appears empty on the screen

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator
import com.swarm.databinding.FragmentBrowseBinding


class BrowseFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding:FragmentBrowseBinding? = null;
    private val binding get() = _binding!!;
    val fragmentsArray = arrayOf(
        "Radar",
        "Match"
    )

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentBrowseBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        val view = binding.root;
        return view;
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val viewPager = binding.browseViewPager
        val tabLayout = binding.browseTabLayout

        val adapter = BrowsePagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = fragmentsArray[position]
        }.attach()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

my main activity

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.swarm.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // set content view
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // set nav
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)

        // set top level destinations
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_feed, R.id.navigation_browse, R.id.navigation_explore, R.id.navigation_inbox
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        // drawer
        binding.apply {
            drawerNavView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.drawerMood -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "First Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    R.id.drawerFilters -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Second Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    R.id.drawerSettings -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "third Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/drawerNavView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_nav_menu" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you checked this with light theme ? Dark theme is applied in device as per screen shot and there are chances that text is not showing due to dark

Comment: Also provide your activity class and layout

Comment: Yes, same thing in light theme.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the **onCreateView** like below.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentBrowseBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        val view = _binding!!.root;
        return view;
    }
```

You to replace the view variable **view = binding.root;** to **view = _binding!!.root;**

Right the binding not returning any view that's why the issue occurs

Comment: When i make this change, i get `Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type FragmentBrowseBinding?` error on the two lines `val viewPager = _binding?.browseViewPager` and `val tabLayout = _binding.browseTabLayout` and if i change them to `_binding?.browserViewPager` and `_binding?.browseTabLayout` i also have to surround TabLayoutMediator function by if non-null blocks and after all that it still doesn't show anything on the screen.

Comment: you have to change only this  _binding = FragmentBrowseBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        val view = _binding!!.root;  two line, rest of all everything is fine.